# StencilJS performance problem with Angular

Tags: html, angular, stenciljs

My team is using a mixture of Angular components and StencilJS components in our application. Some of our pages show a list of items (with a conventional Angular `*ngFor`) and that list length may vary from just a few to perhaps a thousand or more.

The desired behavior is, upon navigating to the page, a busy-wait spinner appears to indicate "system is processing". The data then shows up (either bit at a time or all at once--that does not matter) and then the spinner should disappear, as shown in this timing diagram:

[image]

In practice, for larger quantity of items (say a few hundred or more) the rendering looks like this:
[image]

In other words, the spinner appears then disappears, and a significant number of seconds later (up to 25 seconds, proportional to the list length) the data finally renders!

I have isolated this to the usage of StencilJS components to create an HTML-table-like entity: swapping that out for either (a) a plain HTML `<table>` or (b) an equivalent Angular component `<my-table>` exhibits the desired timing in the first chart.

A couple notes:

- The reason for wanting something other than a plain HTML `<table>` is so that so complex CSS can be encapsulated into the entity.
- Each table row is not particularly complex: perhaps 3 to 5 columns just containing text.

Does this mean we are using StencilJS incorrectly, or is there indeed such a performance penalty for using it?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing some code, specifically the "table" component and how you pass the data to it. A DevTools performance session could help as well, a minimal reproducible example would be perfect. My first guess is that Stencil might not be batching the DOM writes efficiently. Alternatively, you could use a virtual scroll list, e.g. [the one from Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/virtual-scroll).

Comment: Good question but without could examples it's hard to answer...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, folks. Unfortunately I haven't quite figured out how to make a small reproducible example. My hope was that someone might be able to comment more generally with either "Oh, StencilJS has known issues if you do this..." or "No, StencilJS should be very performant so it is probably your code."... and then I could try to work it further.

Comment: Stencil is usually quite fast, even with large DOM manipulation, see [this demo](https://stencil-fiber-demo.firebaseapp.com/). But we might find something if you give more detail, like which components are Angular and which are Stencil (is the list itself a Stencil component or just the items in the list?), how you're passing the data (as a property or inside the tags to a `<slot>`), how/when are you hiding the spinner etc.